# iOS 13 URLSessionWebSocketTask tries to disconnect twice

Tags: swift, websocket, ios13, urlsession, urlsessionwebsockettask

I am trying to implement web socket client with the new URLSession web socket support. Here is my simple implementation:

```
import Foundation

class WebSocketTest: NSObject {
    var session: URLSession?
    var task: URLSessionWebSocketTask?

    init(urlRequest: URLRequest) {
        super.init()
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        self.task = self.session?.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
    }

    public func connect() {
        self.task?.resume()
    }

    public func disconnect() {
        self.task?.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
}

extension WebSocketTest: URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        print("Connected!")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        print("Disconnected!")
    }
}
```

This is my calling code:

```
let url = URL(string: "wss://echo.websocket.org")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("https://example.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
self.webSocketTest = WebSocketTest(urlRequest: request)
self.webSocketTest?.connect()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    self.webSocketTest?.disconnect()
}
```

And this is the output of execution:

```
Connected!
Disconnected!
Disconnected!
Connection 1: received failure notification
```

So, after canceling the task, the socket is trying to be disconnected twice. (I assume the last line of the output is there because it's trying to close already closed socket, otherwise it would be possible that just the delegate method is called twice)

Is it a bug in the framework or in my code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The API is broken, I have an open radar with Apple about this.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Could you please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as correct. Also, it would be helpful if you share the open radar link. Thanks.

Comment: The radar I filed can't be made public (contains work info). However, the issue appears to been fixed in iOS 13.2.2, so I would recommend you give that a try.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen thanks, I will give it a try.